# Cannot get pro*c code to compile with gcc

Tags: gcc, compilation

**ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .main** <-- This is what I can't figure out.

Pro*C/C++: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Dec 14 14:54:27 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from:

```
/orasw/app/oracle/product/10g/db/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg
```

> gcc -w -maix64 -I/orasw/app/oracle/product/10g/db/precomp/public -L/orasw/app/oracle/product/10g/db/lib send_to_audit_tbl.c -I/actapps/batch/sctp/mme/incl -I/orasw/app/oracle/product/10g/db/precomp/public -I/usr/include -I. -I/actapps/batch/sctp/mme/incl /actapps/batch/sctp/mme/bin/Validata.o /orasw/app/oracle/product/10g/db/lib/libclntsh.so -o send_to_audit_tbl
>       **ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .main**

```
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.

collect2: ld returned 8 exit status

make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.


Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, two suggestions:

- Are you sure you have a function called `main` in your files?
- You could follow the compiler's advice: use `Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information`. What does it give, then?